# Mouse wheel not working inside Slimscroll

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, slimscroll

I have used a  slimscroll but unfortunately the mouse wheel is not working to sroll up and down the content.

Here is the code of Slimscroll which i used:-

```
$(".new_notif").slimScroll({
        height:'500px',
        allowPageScroll: false,
        disableFadeOut: true,
        railVisible : true,
        wheelStep: 20
    });
```

Pleas tell what else to do to enable mouse wheel inside slimscroll??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change allow scroll to true?

Answer (score 0):

Change wheelStep: 20 to wheelStep: 1

This worked for me to actually show the scrolling.

```
$(function () {        
    $('.new_notif').slimScroll({         
        color:  '#1b76d5',         
        size:   '10px',         
        height:  '100px',        
        wheelStep:  '1' 
    });
});
```